# Login failed for user 'PHX\XXXXXXXXXXXX$' in Azure SQL

Tags: azure

We have started getting this error from one of our sites hosted in Azure. This is not the user ID that is specified in our connection string and appears to be an internal Azure domain login of some kind. The site has been working fine until this evening and has not been updated.

Other posts on the web indicate this might be an internal SQL Azure issue but not sure how to get this resolved. Azure service dashboard doesn't indicate any outages.

Comment: We have also tried connecting to the SQL Azure database directly from SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials as our connection string and it fails with the same error as above. We are not using the PHX\XXXXXXXXX login to connect so are not sure where this is coming from. We can connect OK using a different login though.

Comment: change the login password, your account might have been compromised.

Comment: we are experiencing a similar issue

Comment: suddenly the issue is resolved for us.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is now resolved for us too and we didn't change a thing. Appears to be an internal Azure problem which is worrying.